# Brew & Ruby no longer functioning properly due to a recursive trap

Tags: macos, bash, ruby, homebrew

After updating to OS X 10.10 (Though this might have been irrelevant), I was not able to run any `brew` commands. Any command gave me this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 26: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

I found that this isn't because `ruby` is missing, but instead because of a change that needs to be made in `/usr/local/Library/brew.rb`.

If I go into that file and replace `#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -W0` with `#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0` `brew` commands do work properly. So great!

However, I can't `brew update` because of this. I now get this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Library/brew.rb
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Most likely the update that will be applied if I merge would fix my original problem, but I can't apply it without changes locally. If I don't change locally, I can't update.

Is there an elegant solution to this that won't break my entire workflow.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for the exact error I found that this was answered at AskDifferent: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153790/how-to-fix-brew-after-its-upgrade-to-yosemite

```
cd /usr/local/Library 
git pull origin master
```

You can just update everything manually with Git. You can't edit `/usr/local/Library/brew.rb` in any way though, or you'll get the same merge problem.